# How to find row indices where duplicated pairs exist

Tags: r

I have a list of data.frames, each data.frame is a separate output of the same format. I can merge all of them into a master list with

```
master <- do.call("rbind", list)
```

I have two columns in particular (1 and 3) in which I want to find duplicates, which I do so with

```
unique.pairs <- unique(master[duplicated(master[,c(1,3)]),c(1,3)])
```

This will give me a data.frame of unique column 1, 3 pairings.

Now I want to find, for each unique pair, where are the other instances of this pair. The ideal output would be a data.frame with one column containing the pairing (can concatenate the string to one) and another containing the row names from master (easily obtainable with the index of duplicates I'm trying to find) where the duplicate exists

A dummy example (stripped down to the two columns of interest):

```
master <- data.frame(A=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5), B=c(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,8))
unique.pairs <- unique(master[duplicated(master,c(1,2)]),c(1,2)])
```

Now I want to be able to make a data.frame as such:

```
results <- data.frame(instance=c("2->3","4->6"), indices=c("3,4","7,8"))
```

I am thinking you iterate through each pair of `unique.pairs` then find where that pair exists in `master`, but I can't figure out the syntax.

Comment: You can `paste` all columns together and make a "character" vector that might be more convenient to search for duplicates (`duplicated.data.frame` does exactly this) -- i.e. `do.call(paste, c(sep = "->", master))` etc. You could, also, consider an approach, e.g., like `aggregate(seq_len(nrow(master)) ~ ., master, identity)` or, even, `split(seq_len(nrow(master)), master, sep = "->", drop = TRUE)` among much more alternatives. instead of `paste`ing vectors.

Comment: To find indices or row names best would be `which()` function by providing the conditions inside for the master list columns

Comment: Typo in your dummy data -- the code does not run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seemed to me there was an error in your `unique.pairs` construction, so I offer this alternate:

```
 unique.pairs <- unique( master[ duplicated(master) ,c(1,2)])
```

This then uses that to construct a vector of your first sort:

```
 grps <- apply( master, 1, function(x) if ( any( duplicated( rbind(unique.pairs, x))) ) { paste(x[1],x[2], sep="->")}else{NA} + )
 grps

#[1] NA     NA     "2->3" "2->3" NA     NA     "4->6" "4->6" NA     NA
```

You can then use that vector to group the other items of interest:

```
> locs <- tapply( rownames(master), grps, function(x) paste(x, collapse=",") )
> as.data.frame(locs)
     locs
2->3  3,4
4->6  7,8
```

Answer (score 7):

With data.table, you can do...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(master)

master[master[, .N, by=names(master)][ N > 1L ], on=names(master), 
  .(N, locs = .(.I)), by=.EACHI]

#    A B N locs
# 1: 2 3 2  3,4
# 2: 4 6 2  7,8
```

Note that we don't even need to construct an object like `unique.pairs`.

`N` is the number of repetitions. You can omit it from output by just using `.(locs = .(.I))`.

Comment: Super Neat way of solving it!